# What are MSP_TOKEN and MSP_ID values in cookies in browsers?

Tags: authentication, cookies, token, access-token

On a site I have visited recently, under cookies it has MSP_ID with value of 9CADF8E0-46AC-4ECE-8962BABDAA681F4D and MSP_TOKEN with a value of ___ (redacted here as I believe it's to do with my account authentication).

What do these mean? Are they derived from a JWT access token? If they are leaked, will it compromise my account? How can I use an access token and a client ID to generate cookie values like these.

I realise that's a lot of questions but answers to any of them would be useful, thanks.